# Will voltage gain change in non-inverting op amp when load is connected?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is there any significant change in amplified output voltage when a load is connected to the output compared to a no-load connection in a non-inverting op-amp? Why?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any significant change in amplified output voltage when a load is connected to the output compared to a no-load connection in a non-inverting op-amp?

No, provided the op-amp's maximum current ratings (or minimum load resistance) is not exceeded.

> Why?

Because the negative feedback will cause the op-amp to adjust its output until the correct output voltage is given.

Answer (score 0):

No - the load will have (practically) no influence on gain because in both cases the output resistance is negligible small and the opamp behaves (nearly) as an ideal voltage source.

The open-loop output resistance of the opamp is drastically reduced due to the negative feedback effect (typically below 1 Ohm).

**EDIT**: Of course, the above explanations are valid only for such frequencies, where the used opamp "behaves as a nearly ideal  opamp" - which means: We are allowed to treat the active device as ideal during calculation of the surrounding passive network - because this was the only reason we have chosen an opamp-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

At high frequencies, where the open loop gain has dropped to only 100, or to 10, the addition of 100 ohms Rload will cause substantial errors in most opamp circuits.

Additionally, the distortion will rise because the differential Vin (between Vin+ and Vin-) is **large** at high frequencies, and requiring more output current requires more Vin which further increases the distortion.

Some opamps will even be upset in accuracy at DC, because of high Rout (10,000 ohms Rout, for some lowpower opamps).

Comment: Yes - I agree to the above comment concerning the high-frequency behaviour. However, in case of such low loop gains (100 or even only 10), we should not overlook the fact that the desired gain value will be not determined anymore by the feedback resistor ratio only. Hence, we have many error sources which contribute to the misbehaviour at such large frequencies.